# How do I power a pump with a Reactor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-buildcraft

So, I built a 5 x 5 reactor.  My next question cannot be as easily answered any where else.  Can I power a BC Factory Pump with A Big Reactor Yellorium passively cooled 5 x 5 reactor.

Bonus:  What site can point me to what all can be powered by a reactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. A Big Reactors reactor produces Redstone Flux (RF). Redstone Flux is converted to Buildcraft power automatically within most energy conduits.

Redstone Flux is a common power system that a lot of mods use. Your reactor should be able to power pretty much anything except for machines from IndustrialCraft2 (and given the right setup, you can convert RF to EU).

Comment: What should I use as a conduit then?

Comment: It depends on what mods you have. EnderIO energy conduits work to convert RF to MJ, MineFactory Reloaded energy cables will work with RF, EU and MJ, the ExtraUtilities Energy Transfer node and energy pipes will convert to MJ natively as well.

Comment: So would I need an EnderIO energy conduit to power this pump?

Comment: I would recommend EnderIO conduits, yes, if you have them.